# Give away signs that a site is Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to alter my site in such a way so that when people view it, they don't know it's powered by Drupal. So, was wondering if there are any signs that give this away that I should know about?

Some of the giveaways I know of, are:

1. When adding content, it will say "node/add".
2. If the following file exists: misc/favicon.ico

etc

I'm looking for similar stuff?

Comment: http://isthissitebuiltwithdrupal.com/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let's look at a fairly customized page based on Drupal: http://gemini-lights.com/ (a random page from the [Drupal sites repository](http://drupal.org/case-studies)).
There are many giveaways:

- if you change www.example.com/link/link2 to www.example.com/?q=link/link2 and it still works and points to the right page
- www.example.com/user/1 gives you a profile page
- resources (imgs, css, etc) are in /sites/all|example.com/themes/ or sth similar
- there are CSS classes applied to many key elements of the site (like `body`) that do not change appearance - Drupal uses them to provide some info about the state of the page (like `<body class="front not-logged-in page-front-page two-sidebars">`)
- probably many others

My advice is: don't try too hard with hiding the CMS of your website, if a hacker wants to find out what CMS you are running, he/she will find out. I'd focus on keeping the CMS up-to-date (Drupal makes this easy) and also watching out which modules you are installing - *they* are the most likely attack vectors.

---

Since this question is still getting many hits, let me update it with an example of a website of a major company (one of the biggest telephone companies in Poland), that, to my (pleasant) surprise ,is using Drupal for its main site, http://dialog.pl/:

- The usual giveaway pages like /user/1, /login, etc. redirect to main page, so you can see the creators of the site have done their homework ;)
- ...but the source of the page contains my favourite give away: the usage of the zen theme: urls like `/sites/all/themes/zen-dialog-main-page/../zen/css/page-strona_glowna.php` or CSS styles applied: `<body class="front not-logged-in node-type-page two-sidebars">`
- One more give away is the [update.php](http://dialog.pl/update.php) page that has the familiar Garland theme (props to [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516599/give-away-signs-that-a-site-is-drupal/2505206#2505206) for this one).

As you can see, it's still possible to tell that the website is using Drupal - and this is a website of a major corporation. So the above advice still holds: don't waste your resources on trying to hide the CMS you used, keep it up to date (that's why the update.php file is probably still in place), monitor security vulnerabilities, use strong passwords, etc.

Comment: Not sure if  is actually a good example of a Drupal customized website anymore.. when checking with [builtwith](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn?hl=en) it shows up as a Joomla website actually..

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are still using Drupal - all the hints I've given above are pointing to it, especially the update.php page. I don't know what exactly convinced `builtwith` to mark it as built with Joomla (maybe a component they are using on the main page), but in the end it's only guessing so you should double check they results it returns.

Comment: The http://www.losttheatre.co.uk/? Well, a great clue it's Joomla and NOT Drupal is that in the footer they mention the site was built by http://www.webeditors.co.uk, which is a Joomla shop.. just saying..

Comment: My mistake - I thought you meant dialog.pl. Thank you for pointing this out - I've updated the answer, picking a new site at random :)

Comment: You'd also have to check the css of every module you installed and modify. This would be s serious barrier to applying any new security policies.

Answer (score 18):

You're wasting your time:

Obscurity is not a form of security. And trying to hide Drupal may only tempt a hacker to beat you.

If there is a security flaw, you will almost certainly miss it and the hacker only has to try a specific attack vector. He or she is not going to check if it's Drupal or not. Your attack may come from software that won't care.

The changes you make to hide Drupal may actually make your site less secure. Especially if you change the core and are no longer able to tell if your site is up-to-date.

It's very likely that the effort you spend hiding Drupal can, instead be applied to a proven, effective security policy and get better results.

Comment: Most script kiddie attacks won't check for a certain software or version and then attack; they will just run a set of exploits and see if any work.  If they do, then they can check what software and version they broke if they care.  Hiding the obvious version information may at most cause an attack to take longer, since the set of attacks to run can't be limited.

Comment: I understand the argument but obscurity is definitely a form of security. Its much harder to hit a target if you don't know it's there in the first place..

Comment: Are you sure? This would definitely be the case for an unknown security hole. But once something is known you only need to automate an attack. It happened to rails recently.

Comment: Ok, let's use an analogy that I'm sure everyone understands then.. is a stealth fighter jet safer than a regular jet?.. it's really easy to hit both if you know where they are, but I'm sure we all agree the stealth one is more secure due to its obscurity

Answer (score 5):

- Login page is /user or /user/login
- Admin page is /admin or ?q=admin
- /node displays a listing of the latest nodes
- /node/n where n is a number displays the node with that number (for example /node/1 displays the first node ever created)
- The word 'node' or 'views' in objects' classes in view source.
- In things which are paginated, page 2 is actually displayed as page/1 or /1 in the URL (Drupal pagination URLs are sort of geeky like that).

Like others have said, don't worry too much about this. It's a waste of time. Just keep Drupal core and all your modules up to date (you can even set it to email you when security releases are released for your installed modules) and you shouldn't have to worry about a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Quick ways to find out if a site is a Drupal site.

- Browse the source code and search for or Drupal.settings (appears on all sites using the google analytics module)
- go to www.example.com/CHANGELOG.txt if Drupalsite, will show the current version.

There are a lot of other ways that indicate if a site is a Drupal site, but the above is fast and certain.

Other signs would be.

- markup:

  - <div id="node-2020 ... (divs with id node-[number])
  - <div class="views- ... (divs with a class of views-[something]
  - class="clear-block" (clear-block is the drupal implementation of the clear-fix CSS trick)
- Urls:

  - node
  - node/[number]
  - node/add
  - admin -> giving 403
  - admin/build/modules -> giving a 403
- HTTP Expires header set to Dries' (the creator of Drupal) birthday

Comment: Angie Byron of Lullabot wrote an article about the HTTP Expires header (http://www.lullabot.com/articles/is-site-running-drupal) and the comments have some other good information and links for identifying Drupal sites

Answer (score 4):

[greggles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56791/greggles) (lead of the Drupal Security team) wrote an article about hiding the fact a site is running Drupal: [Hiding the fact your site runs Drupal OR fingerprinting a Drupal site](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/hiding-fact-your-site-runs-drupal-or-fingerprinting-drupal-site).

Some of the things that allow to know when a site is using Drupal can be altered, but in some cases it is not worth, or it requires resources that would be better spent doing something else, such as making Drupal more secure, or avoiding security holes in the site.
For example, the messages given to the users from the modules are an indication the site is running Drupal (and what version exactly), but altering those messages would mean change them every time a new module is installed, or a new version of a module is installed. The CSS classes is something else that helps understanding when a site is running Drupal, but changing them is not that easy, as some modules depend on a specific CSS class to work. The fact the JavaScript code uses a `Drupal` object also helps in catching a Drupal site.

Answer (score 3):

New Answer to old question.  [This site](http://isthissitebuiltwithdrupal.com/) will tell you if a site is built with Drupal, and could give your game away.  It does give false negatives though, so it might be worth it to test it out with that website and see how well you can obfuscate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really escape people's suspicions. To do so, you'd have to change file-systems, stylesheets, markup, etc. This is unreasonable. Why does it matter if you're using Drupal?

Comment: I am sure he is worried that people will use known vulnarabilities in Drupal.

Comment: @whatnick: yes, basically. I'd just feel a lot better if people didn't know what my site is running on. it makes it that bit harder to find holes.

Answer (score 2):

I find http://wappalyzer.com Chrome extension an excellent tool for detecting what a site is powered by. This goes beyond detecting just Drupal and lists many of the 3rd party tools and underlying technologies a site uses.

Answer (score 1):

People who knows Drupal may identify it by the source. But Drupal has no Generator Header like Joomla or others.

Comment: I meant, if they just had to access my site, without being able to see the source.

Comment: if you can access the site, you also have access to the source. ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry. You have access to the HTML source. I was implying you don't have access to the actual php source code. Guess that's obvious..

Answer (score 1):

The expires headers are pretty unique as well. In fact they are set to Dries Buytaert (creator of Drupal) date of birth. As far as I can tell they have been set like the below since Drupal 4.6.

```
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Dead giveaway:

Try going to update.php, you'll get Access Denied (and the Garland theme).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an add-on called Chrome Sniffer that shows what CMS any site is built on.

Comment: Firefox has one too https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/